# different vertical alignment on chrome on pc vs. mac when using @font-face with custom icon font created using IcoMoon

Tags: css, svg, font-face, custom-font

On Chrome for PC, it seems like custom fonts are always positioned to the baseline (which might be correct, however it's insistent with other browsers)

Here's the JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/hLVZU/12/

Solved though (as you can see from the fiddle)...will elaborate in answer

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be relative to the tallest character. To fix I created a character that spanned all the way to the bottom of the grid provided by IcoMoon (I don't understand fonts that well, but I'm not so sure how this would work if you wanted to create a character with an actual accender)

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the SVG font IDs in your @font-face rule were not correct. See this jsfiddle with the correct font IDs: http://jsfiddle.net/hLVZU/13/

Regardless of this, I'm trying to find out what is causing the difference between different formats.

Answer (score 1):

I have now updated the app and the generated fonts should no longer have this issue when you only select small glyphs.